# WARNING: Unsupported component-family/renderer-type: org.omnifaces.component.script/javax.faces.Button

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, renderer, omnifaces

I have the following form defined:

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <h:form
        id="posForm"
        styleClass="well span12">
....
        <o:commandScript
            id="createTransactionCommandScript"
            rendered="#{multiTenantBean.currentAccount.stripePublishableKey != null}"
            name="createTransaction"
            actionListener="#{posMB.createTransaction}"
            execute="@form"
            render="@form" />
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

When I load my page, I get this error spit to Stdout repeatedly:

```
Apr 11, 2013 6:31:53 PM org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlRenderKitImpl getRenderer
WARNING: Unsupported component-family/renderer-type: org.omnifaces.component.script/javax.faces.Button
Apr 11, 2013 6:31:53 PM javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase getRenderer
WARNING: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /pos.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody,Id: j_id_m][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: posForm][Class: org.omnifaces.component.script.CommandScript,Id: createTransactionCommandScript]} (component-family=org.omnifaces.component.script, renderer-type=javax.faces.Button)
Apr 11, 2013 6:31:53 PM org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlRenderKitImpl getRenderer
WARNING: Unsupported component-family/renderer-type: org.omnifaces.component.script/javax.faces.Button
Apr 11, 2013 6:31:53 PM javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase getRenderer
WARNING: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /pos.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody,Id: j_id_m][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: posForm][Class: org.omnifaces.component.script.CommandScript,Id: createTransactionCommandScript]} (component-family=org.omnifaces.component.script, renderer-type=javax.faces.Button)
Apr 11, 2013 6:31:53 PM org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlRenderKitImpl getRenderer
WARNING: Unsupported component-family/renderer-type: org.omnifaces.component.script/javax.faces.Button
Apr 11, 2013 6:31:53 PM javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase getRenderer
WARNING: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /pos.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody,Id: j_id_m][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: posForm][Class: org.omnifaces.component.script.CommandScript,Id: createTransactionCommandScript]} (component-family=org.omnifaces.component.script, renderer-type=javax.faces.Button)
Apr 11, 2013 6:31:53 PM org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlRenderKitImpl getRenderer
WARNING: Unsupported component-family/renderer-type: org.omnifaces.component.script/javax.faces.Button
Apr 11, 2013 6:31:53 PM javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase getRenderer
WARNING: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /pos.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody,Id: j_id_m][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: posForm][Class: org.omnifaces.component.script.CommandScript,Id: createTransactionCommandScript]} (component-family=org.omnifaces.component.script, renderer-type=javax.faces.Button)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong. The [`CommandScript`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/component/script/CommandScript.html) has inherited the renderer type of `javax.faces.Button` from the [`UICommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html) class which it extends from, while it should [actually](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#setRendererType%28java.lang.String%29) have been set to `null` as the `CommandScript` renders by itselves. MyFaces was just warning that the associated renderer implementation couldn't be resolved. This is fixed in OmniFaces 1.5.